# Set icon in React Admin ChipField conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

I have a `ChipField` in my `Datagrid` in my React Admin App which shows a `text` property. Now, I'd like to add an icon to that `ChipField` by using the icon prop. Since the `ChipField` can have one of five static values, the icon should change according to the text.

My approach is:

```
    export const IOList = props => {   
    
    function getTypeImage(id) {
        console.log(id);
        switch(id) {
            case "image": return <ImageIcon />;
            case "document": return <FormatColorTextIcon />;
            case "audio": return <AudiotrackIcon />;
            case "video": return <VideocamIcon />;
            case "location": return <LocationOnIcon />;
        }
        
    }
    return(<List filters={IOFilters} {...props}> {
    <Datagrid>
            <TextField source="id" />
            <TextField source="name" />
            <ChipField source="type" choices={choices} icon={getTypeImage(record.type)}/>
    </Datagrid>
    </List>);
    };
```

But I wouldn't be here if that worked.

In fact, *record* is unknown. If I remove the function parameter entirely and return e.g. `return <AudiotrackIcon />` the icon is displayed.
My question is how to access the record displayed in each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you are trying to pass a JSX component as a prop of ChipField
You should pass JSX as a children
`<ChipField source="type" ...> {getTypeImage(record.type)} </ChipField>`

I dont know where you're picking record datas, but this is not a "wonderful" solution, A better option is to deprecate ChipField component, because at the moment is just a wrapper used like a high order component

Map `record` in `IOList` and save the right Icon component in a const, and then print it

`const icon = getTypeImage(record.data)`

```
    <Datagrid>
<TextField source="id" />
<TextField source="name" />
{icon}
</Datagrid>
```